# React Native Flat List doesn't call onEndReached handler after two successful calls

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I implement a very simple list that calls a server that returns a page containing books.Each book has a title, author, id, numberOfPages, and price). I use a Flat List in order to have infinite scrolling and it does its job very well two times in a row (it loads the first three pages) but later it doesn't trigger the handler anymore.

Initially it worked very well by fetching all available pages, but it stopped working properly after I added that extra check in local storage. If a page is available in local storage and it has been there no longer than 5 seconds I don't fetch the data from the server, instead I use the page that is cached. Of course, if there is no available page or it is too old I fetch it from the server and after I save it in local storage.(Something went wrong after adding this behavior related to local storage.)

Here is my component:

```
export class BooksList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 0
        };
    }

    async storePage(page, currentTime) {
        try {
            page.currentTime = currentTime;
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(`page${page.page}`, JSON.stringify(page));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    subscribeToStore = () => {
        const { store } = this.props;
        this.unsubsribe = store.subscribe(() => {
            try {
                const { isLoading, page, issue } = store.getState().books;
                if (!issue && !isLoading && page) {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading,
                        books: (this.state.books ?
                            this.state.books.concat(page.content) :
                            page.content),
                        issue
                    }, () => this.storePage(page, new Date()));
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.subscribeToStore();
        // this.getBooks();
        this.loadNextPage();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubsribe();
    }

    loadNextPage = () => {
        this.setState({ pageNumber: this.state.pageNumber + 1 },
            async () => {
                let localPage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`page${this.state.pageNumber}`);
                let pageParsed = JSON.parse(localPage);
                if (localPage && (new Date().getTime() - localPage.currentTime) < 5000) {
                    this.setState({
                        books: (
                            this.state.books ?
                                this.state.books.concat(pageParsed.content) :
                                page.content),
                        isLoading: false,
                        issue: null
                    });
                } else {
                    const { token, store } = this.props;
                    store.dispatch(fetchBooks(token, this.state.pageNumber));
                }
            });

    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, issue, books } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator animating={isLoading} size='large' />
                {issue && <Text>issue</Text>}
                {books && <FlatList
                    data={books}
                    keyExtractor={book => book.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <BookView key={item.id} title={item.title} author={item.author}
                            pagesNumber={item.pagesNumber} />
                    )}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
                    onEndReached={this.loadNextPage}
                />}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

In the beginning the pageNumber available in the state of the component is 0, so the first time when I load the first page from the server it will be incremented before the rest call.

And here is the action fetchBooks(token, pageNumber):

```
export const fetchBooks = (token, pageNumber) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOAD_STARTED });
    fetch(`${httpApiUrl}/books?pageNumber=${pageNumber}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': token
        }
    })
        .then(page => page.json())
        .then(pageJson => dispatch({ type: LOAD_SUCCEDED, payload: pageJson }))
        .catch(issue => dispatch({ type: LOAD_FAILED, issue }));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe changing the threshold to a number greater than zero helps (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14312#issuecomment-311958190 and https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold)

Comment: You, it did the trick. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!